# Render decal on additional polygon

Tags: c++, opengl, decal

I want to export difficult model to OBJ format and render it on iPad. The most of the work performed. But there is the following problem.
For render decals I need to use additional polygon. For calculate UV coordinates I use Exponential Mapping algorithm. after applying this algorithm I get mesh with texture coordinates, but this algorithm use big radious(a lot of triangles). And after all I get something like this:
[image]

A lot of triangles but moste of them is not need.How can I remove additional tiangles and moove points to get correctsize of decal.

Or more simle example.
If I has a rectungle (2 triangles and 4 points) with texture (not in 0..1 range). And I want to find another 4 point (with texture coordinates in 0..1 range). Ok, if you see the image I has black triangles  and I want to get red triangles.
[image]

How can i get positions of red triangles point (x, y ,z coordinates of  all 4 point).

Comment: What do you know about this image? Is it placed in centre and covers some known percentage or rectangle?

Comment: I have UV coordinates and positions in 3d space. I want to get new position with UV coordinates like on image (red text). I think it's associated with barycentric coordinates.

Comment: It is unlikely you'll have an answer if noone could understand what you want to do. Is black and red images texture space are the same, and you want to calculate corresponding points from their UV? In that case why image diagonals don't match? Describe with few well-defined sentences what you want to get and by what criterias you'll see difference between 'wrong' and 'right' solution.